# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'testMethod' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have following code for **component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  Linecap = {};
  dataArray=[];

  constructor(private chartGetDataService: ChartGetDataService) {
 }

  ngOnInit(): void {
         this.chartPlotting();
  }


public testMethod(){
  this.chartGetDataService.getLatestData1().subscribe( list=>{ this.dataArray=list.map(item=>{return item.payload.val()});} );
  console.log(this.dataArray);
  return this.dataArray;
 }

public chartPlotting(){

  this.Linecap= new Chart('canvas',
  {
   type: 'line',
   data: { labels: [moment().toDate().getTime()], datasets: [{ label:'Flow',yAxisID: 'A',lineTension: 0, data: [] , borderColor: '#3cb371', fill: false ,borderWidth:2},
                                                            ]
         },
   options: { responsive: true,animation: {duration: 0},hover: {animationDuration: 0},responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
              scales: { xAxes: [{ type: 'realtime',time: { parser: undefined} , display: true }],
                        yAxes: [{ id:'A', display: true, ticks: { beginAtZero: true, fontColor:'#f4af07',  stepSize: 10, max: 100}},
                                ]
                      },

              plugins: {  streaming: {
                      duration: 60000,
                      refresh: 2000,
                      delay: 3000,
                      pause: false,
                      ttl: undefined,
                      frameRate: 2,
                      onRefresh: function(Linecap) {

                        console.log(this.testMethod())
                        console.log(this.dataArray)

                                                                        Linecap.data.datasets[0].data.push({x: Date.now(), y: this.dataArray[2] });
                        Linecap.update({ preservation: true });
                        }

                    }
},

}

})

}
```

I am stuck with 2 problems in this code.

1. My first console.log in **testMethod()** returns desired value that means method is working fine and values are stored in **dataArray** but when I try to read **dataArray** inside **onRefresh**  `Linecap.data.datasets[0].data.push({x: Date.now(), y: this.dataArray[2] });` function it gives me error **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataArray' of undefined**
2. If I call testMethod in onRefresh function like `var ws=this.testMethod()` it gives me error **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'testMethod' of undefined**. Subsequent call of `console.log(this.testMethod())` is also throwing same error

What wrong I am doing? I am not able to find it. How do I solve undefined error for this code. If I call testMethod outside onRefresh function it works perfectly but it returns empty dataArray.

Answer (score 2):

Meaning of `this` keyword in a Javascript function depends on the usage. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) for more details.

Either way it will not refer to the scope of the class. To refer to the scope of the class using the `this` keyword, use [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Try the following

```js
plugins: {  
    .
    .
    .
    onRefresh: (Linecap) => {
      console.log(this.testMethod())
      console.log(this.dataArray)
      Linecap.data.datasets[0].data.push({x: Date.now(), y: this.dataArray[2] });
      Linecap.update({ preservation: true });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope inside the `onRefresh` function is different than the component scope so `this` is undefined 
use instead an arrow function for the `onRefresh` like this

```
onRefresh: (Linecap)  => { ... }
```