# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at .addTo(this.map)

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl

I am using mapbox in my angular application. I am trying to place markers on the map. I followed the mapbox example and changed it to angular

```
geojson.features.forEach(function (marker) {

      //   // create a HTML element for each feature
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      if (marker.properties.on_ground == true)
        el.className = 'marker-on_ground';
      else
        el.className = 'marker-air';

      // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
      new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(this.map);

    });
```

But when I save this I am getting an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at .addTo(this.map)

Comment: where is map declared?

Comment: Try using Arrow function in the forEach callback.

Comment: Yes, you probably need to use `geojson.features.forEach(marker => {` to keep the `this` referencing your class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'testMethod' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61551420/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-testmethod-of-undefined)

Comment: @AshishRanjan your solution worked. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by using Arrow function as suggested by @[Ashish Rajan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976422/ashish-ranjan). I changed my code as fallow

```
geojson.features.forEach((marker) => {

  //   // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  if (marker.properties.on_ground == true)
    el.className = 'marker-on_ground';
  else
    el.className = 'marker-air';

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(this.map);

});
```